# Change Active directory in Shell Script

Tags: bash, shell

I'm really new in the shell-department. So i want to change the directory in my shell-script. I've tried many different "solutions" from stackoverflow. But nothing seems to work. Here my Code:

```
runas webuserA
cd /usr/webapps/myApp/deploy
cp /tmp/myFile ./
exit
runas webuserB
```

The script won't change the active directory. I've tried to run it with the following commands:

```
source ./runIt.sh
. runIt.sh
bash runIt.sh
sh runIt.sh
```

What do I have to change in the script or in the start-command?

Comment: What's `runas`?  Are you looking for `sudo`?

Comment: Just `cd` works like you expect, but your script doesn't appear to be doing anything after changing directory.  Try to write a simple script like `cd dirA; pwd; cd dirB; pwd` to see that the current directory does indeed change.  When the script ends, the parent process (your interactive shell) will still be in the directory where you started, of course.

Comment: @tripleee No, `runas` is a command on the server to change the active user.

Comment: Sounds like a Windows server, then?  Anyway, the way these commands usually work is that `sudo sh -c 'cd /path; pwd` will spawn a new shell and once that finishes, you are back in the directory where you started, and back as the user you started as.

Answer (score 0):

Following is the problem line in your script:

```
exit
```

Remove it, and execute your script by either saying:

```
source runIt.sh
```

or

```
. runIt.sh
```

You might have observed that your session would have exited upon invoking the script using  either of the two forms mentioned above.  This is because using `source` or `.` cause the script to run in the same shell.